# displaytag dynamic columns from database

Tags: spring, struts2, displaytag

i want using display tag in struts2 web application for display data from database. The data display dynamically change table name and show the data. how to display dynamic column in jsp.
i used following code. it's working one row only. how to add multiple row  in display table?

```
  public class TableDataDyno {

private ArrayList<Object> dynaBeans;
public TableDataDyno()
{
    dynaBeans = new ArrayList<Object>();

    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One","5"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One","6"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One","7"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One","8"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One","9"));

    dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", "5"));
    dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", "6"));
    dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", "7"));
    dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", "8"));
    dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", "9"));


    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", "5"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", "6"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", "7"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", "8"));
    dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", "9"));

}
public ArrayList<Object> getdynaBeans() {
    return dynaBeans;
}

    public class DynaBean {
private String title;
  private String value;
      public DynaBean(String title, String value) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }
        public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

}

```
         java.util.ArrayList outerBeans = new java.util.ArrayList();
               for(int i=0; i< 2 ; i++)
               {
                 outerBeans.add(new TableDataDyno());
               }
                System.out.println(outerBeans);
   request.setAttribute("items", outerBeans);



        <display:table uid="item" name="items">
   <c:forEach var="cl" items="${item.dynaBeans }" varStatus="index">
       <display:column title="${cl.title}" property="dynaBeans[${index.index}].value"  />
   </c:forEach>
```

output is:[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is: One Two Three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made little bit change

In **TableDataDyno.java**

```
public class TableDataDyno {
private ArrayList<DynaBean> dynaBeans;

public TableDataDyno(int number)
{
        dynaBeans = new ArrayList<DynaBean>();
        dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One",number));
        dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", number));
        dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", number));
}
public ArrayList<DynaBean> getdynaBeans() {
    return dynaBeans;
}
}
```

in **jsp file**

```
java.util.ArrayList<TableDataDyno> outerBeans = new java.util.ArrayList<TableDataDyno>();
for(int i=5; i< 10 ; i++)
{
    outerBeans.add(new TableDataDyno(i));
}

request.setAttribute("items", outerBeans);

<display:table uid="item" name="items">
  <c:forEach var="cl" items="${item.dynaBeans }" varStatus="index">
      <display:column title="${cl.title}" property="dynaBeans[${index.index}].value"  />
  </c:forEach>
</display:table>
```

gives **output**

> One  Two   Three
>
> 5     5       5
>
> 6     6       6
>
> 7     7       7
>
> 8     8       8
>
> 9     9       9

But still for different values we need solution

If I make **DynaBean.java** as

```
 public class DynaBean {
private String title;
  private List<String> value;
      public DynaBean(String title, List<String> value) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }
        public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
 }
```

And **TableDataDyno.java** as

```
 public class TableDataDyno {
private ArrayList<DynaBean> dynaBeans;

  public TableDataDyno()
{
        dynaBeans = new ArrayList<DynaBean>();
        List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr1.add("5");
        arr1.add("6");
        arr1.add("7");
        arr1.add("10");
        
        dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("One",arr1));
        List<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr2.add("5");
        arr2.add("6");
        arr2.add("7");
        arr2.add("11");

        dynaBeans.add (new DynaBean("Two", arr2));
        
        List<String> arr3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr3.add("5");
        arr3.add("6");
        arr3.add("7");
        arr3.add("13");

        dynaBeans.add(new DynaBean("Three", arr3));

}
public ArrayList<DynaBean> getdynaBeans() {
    return dynaBeans;
}
 }
```

then **output** is

> ```
> One          Two     Three
> ```
>
> [5, 6, 7, 10] [5, 6, 7, 11] [5, 6, 7, 13]
>
> [5, 6, 7, 10] [5, 6, 7, 11] [5, 6, 7, 13]

Still not getting expected output

Now there is a little trick in **jsp** page

```
 <display:table uid="item" name="items">
    <c:forEach var="cl" items="${item.dynaBeans }" varStatus="index">
        <display:column title="${cl.title}"    >
            <display:table uid="b" name="${cl.value}">
                    <c:out value="${b}"></c:out>
            </display:table>
        </display:column>
   </c:forEach>
  </display:table>
```

And **output** is your **expected output**

> One Two Three
>
> 5   5     5
>
> 6   6     6
>
> 7   7     7
>
> 10   11     13

Finally we got it !!!! :)